# How to use WiFi and Ethernet at same time?

Tags: wifi, esp32, ethernet, modbus-tcp

I am working on a project that requires utilizing WiFi for a mesh network and Ethernet for connecting the ESP32 to another device via ModBus TCP simultaneously. In the Modbus TCP example, I am utilizing netif, and my WiFi solution also employs netif. Whenever i merge both sets of code, the system consistently restarts. Is it possible to use netif for both networks and how can i ensure that their configurations are corrects and that they operate independently?

Sincerely.